# Postgresql wal saving for standby servers that go offline

Tags: postgresql, replication

I use postgresql 9.1 replication to a lot of workstations that have postgresql on hot standby mode. However sometimes these workstations go offline and disconnect from the master server. If they go offline for more than say a day they stop replicating, because the wal segments are no longer available. My question is how do I properly configure the master and the standby servers so that they can still replicate even after being disconnected from each other for several days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up WAL archiving. If the master no longer retains enough WAL your replica will fall back to its `archive_command`.

See [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html) and [this post I wrote earlier](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/58555/7788).

Comment: This is what I did:
1. Edit postgresql.conf on the master and set 
   wal_level = hot_standy
   archive_mode = on
   archive_command = ' cp "%p" /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/walarchive/"%f" '

2. Edit recovery.conf on each of the standy servers and set:
   standby_mode = 'on'
   restore_command = 'cp /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/walarchive/"%f" "%p"'

3. create the directory /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/walarchive and have in read/writable for postgres user

4. Periodically delete old wal segments (older than say 1 month) so the walarchive directory doesn't become bloated.

Please confirm is this is right. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidNoriega Is `/var/lib/pgsql/9.1/walarchive` on NFS, or some other kind of shared file system? If not, how will the replicas read the WAL archives?

Comment: That is what is not clear to me. I thought the master will fetch the archive wal segment as per the restore_command from the recovery.conf on the standby server. So I must have a NFS or someway to share the wal segment files with the master and replicas?

Comment: @DavidNoriega The usual solution is to provide shared storage somewhere. Lots of people now use object stores like S3 for this (see https://github.com/wal-e/wal-e), but you can just as well rsync/scp to a fileserver, or whatever.